# Como puedo sacar la variable de la funcion?

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como sacar la variable debugTemperature de la funcion handleSlider, para poderla usar en los condicionales de abajo. (Necesito añadir mas palabras ni caso a esto :))

```
                //Debug
                let slider= document.querySelector('#slider')
                slider.addEventListener('input', handleSlider)
                let debugTemperature
                function handleSlider(){
                    debugTemperature= slider.value 
                }
                console.log(debugTemperature)


                //Background
                let body= document.getElementById('body')
                let tiempoStandard= '#254594'
                let buenTiempoVerde= '#42A93C'
                let medioTiempoCalorNaranja= '#C49420'
                let malTiempoCalorRojo= '#D0441A'
                let muyMalTiempoCalorVioleta= '#410F88'
                let medioTiempoFrioGris= '#7E7676'
                if(debugTemperature <= 17 ){
                    body.style.backgroundColor= buenTiempoVerde
                } else if(debugTemperature <= 25){
                    body.style.backgroundColor= medioTiempoCalorNaranja
                } else if(debugTemperature <= 30){
                    body.style.backgroundColor= malTiempoCalorRojo
                } else if(debugTemperature >= 31){
                    body.style.backgroundColor= muyMalTiempoCalorVioleta
                } else if(debugTemperature <= 9){
                    body.style.backgroundColor= medioTiempoFrioGris
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lograrlo debes de tener en cuenta el [Ámbito de Variables en Javascript](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/javascript/capitulo-4/ambito-de-las-variables). Consiste en variables que se pueden acceder desde cualquier parte del código `globales` y otras solo desde la función donde se declaran `local`.

Estas usando `let` para declarar la variables y eso crea variables `locales` si deseas acceder desde otra función o parte de código a `debugTemperature` debes declararla como `var` recomendablemente al principio de tu código; Así podrás dividir tu función de escucha de cambio `handlerSlider` que actualiza el valor de `debugTemperature` y ademas crear una función separada que actualiza la vista, la llame `updateStatus`.

Te en cuenta ademas que cambiar el valor de la variable dentro de `eventListener` no hará que tu código de actualización corra solo, debes igual llamarlo cada vez que se actualice osea después de hacer `debugTemperature= slider.value`.

```js
// declaro las variables y funciones
var debugTemperature = 0

function handleSlider(){
    debugTemperature= slider.value 
    updateStatus()
}

function updateStatus(){
  //Background
  let body= document.getElementById('body')
  let tiempoStandard= '#254594'
  let buenTiempoVerde= '#42A93C'
  let medioTiempoCalorNaranja= '#C49420'
  let malTiempoCalorRojo= '#D0441A'
  let muyMalTiempoCalorVioleta= '#410F88'
  let medioTiempoFrioGris= '#7E7676'
  if(debugTemperature <= 17 ){
      body.style.backgroundColor= buenTiempoVerde
  } else if(debugTemperature <= 25){
      body.style.backgroundColor= medioTiempoCalorNaranja
  } else if(debugTemperature <= 30){
      body.style.backgroundColor= malTiempoCalorRojo
  } else if(debugTemperature >= 31){
      body.style.backgroundColor= muyMalTiempoCalorVioleta
  } else if(debugTemperature <= 9){
      body.style.backgroundColor= medioTiempoFrioGris
  }
}

// ejecuto el codigo
var slider= document.querySelector('#slider')
slider.addEventListener('input', handleSlider)
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" name="points" min="0" max="31">
<div id="body">
TEMPERATURA
</div>
```